# change uitableviewcell highlight does not work

Tags: iphone

I used the codes below to change the highlight color of uitabelviewcell

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface KUITableViewCell : UITableViewCell


-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated;
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
#import "KUITableViewCell.h"

@implementation KUITableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    if (highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    } else 
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}

@end
```

setHighlighted was triggered, but does not change the hight color of the UITableviewCell

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the cell is highlighted, it's `selectedBackgroundView` is displayed meaning your code works correctly and you are doing the "highlighted color" change in a wrong way. To see the color changed, you will want to change the `selectedBackgroundView`.

Comment: I know the way to use selectedBackgroundView , but it is not perfect for model group uitableview , for the first cell and the last cell, it always change the round corner to rectangle

Comment: Check this tutorial for the simplest solution: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html